# How to Compare two BitArray and return indices of differences from second array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two `BitArray` objects. and want to check if the values change compare to first `BitArray` then return indices of second array. I have tried looping over each bit but it takes too much time i.e: I have below two objects:

```
BitArray a = new BitArray{true,false,true};
BitArray b = new BitArray{false,false,false};
```

and want to return result 0,2 because BitArray b has two change compared to BitArray a.

Comment: how large are the inputs usually? meaning: do you actually *need* `BitArray` here? But: to compute the delta: "xor"; however, I don't know that `BitArray` exposes primitives to find the non-zeros (popcount etc). If the data is *large*, however, I wonder whether this might be something to do via SIMD; it seems like it would be pretty trivial with `Vector<int>` or similar

Comment: The BitArray are something around 1024 in length

Answer (score 2):

If performance is your main goal here, you're not going to get there using `BitArray`; that abstraction is simply not optimal. You probably want to drop to your own oversized integer buffers, use "xor" on each to compute the delta, then use bit operations on the delta (xor result).

---

However, on .NET Core 3, you have direct access to the x86 instruction set, giving us both SIMD and popcnt; we can combine those things nicely here, using a SIMD XOR and then popcnt on the delta (there is no SIMD popcnt AFAIK, but we can unroll manually):

```cs
        // make sure these are multiples of 128-bit, so: 4; otherwise
        // you'll have to deal with the leftover bits manually
        uint[] left = new uint[16], right = new uint[16];
        Random rand = new Random(12345);
        for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++)
            left[i] = (uint)rand.Next();
        for (int i = 0; i < right.Length; i++)
            right[i] = (uint)rand.Next();

        // real(ish) code starts here

        // loop over our `uint[]` as spans of Vector128<uint>
        var lspan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<uint, Vector128<uint>>(left);
        var rspan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<uint, Vector128<uint>>(right);
        uint count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lspan.Length; i++)
        {
            // compute the bit delta
            var delta = Popcnt.Xor(lspan[i], rspan[i]);
            // Vector128 is 4xUInt32, so: unroll
            count += Popcnt.PopCount(delta.GetElement(0))
                + Popcnt.PopCount(delta.GetElement(1))
                + Popcnt.PopCount(delta.GetElement(2))
                + Popcnt.PopCount(delta.GetElement(3));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

You could also use the more generic `Vector<T>` for the xor (which works on .NET Framework too, and can handle wider sizes than 128), but: no direct popcount then; example:

```cs
        // loop over our `uint[]` as spans of Vector<uint>
        var lspan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<uint, Vector<uint>>(left);
        var rspan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<uint, Vector<uint>>(right);
        for(int i = 0; i < lspan.Length; i++)
        {
            // compute the bit delta
            var delta = lspan[i] ^ rspan[i];

            // work with delta...
        }
```

This (`Vector<T>`) will commonly give you SIMD widths of 256, or possibly even 512.

Comment: is there any other way than looping  for(int i = 0; i < lspan.Length; i++)
        {
            // compute the bit delta
            var delta = lspan[i] ^ rspan[i];

            // work with delta...
        }

Comment: i dont want to loop through....Array.Except() will return different values kind of what i need for indices

Comment: @HetaSoni `Except` just *hides* the loop; it is still looping, but now you're using a huge heap of abstractions that make it perform much worse than a simple loop and simple bit operators such as "xor"

Answer (score 0):

If the element count for bit arrays is the same then you can you use the following -

```
IList<int> differentIndices = new List<int>();
for(int i=0;i<a.Count;i++)
{
   if (a[i] ^ b[i])
   {
       differentIndices.Add(i);
   }
}
```

Just use XOR operation

Comment: i dont want to loop through...i want something like Array.Except(a) which returns different values, but i need those indices